# How can this warning of InteropServices.SEHException be real?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, exception, c++-cli

I prevent unmanaged C++ exceptions from escaping from my C++/CLI code by wrapping unmanaged calls with exception frames where I catch `const std::exception&`.  But I've got a code-path in which the unmanaged C++ `throw` immediately triggers a warning of `SEHException`, even though there is clearly a catch clause higher up the stack frame in C++/CLI to intercept it.

I do not understand where the `SEHException` can be happening.  I am wondering if it is real at all.

Here is the C++ code throwing the exception way down in the call stack.

```
StringMap ParseTopLevelMap(std::istream& in)
{
    StringMap yamlmap;
    if (!TryParseTopLevelMap(in, yamlmap))
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to parse map");  // Causes SEHException warning.

    return yamlmap;
}
```

The moment I make the `throw` above, I immediately get this output in the output window:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in MyCompany.Sdk_v143.dll
```

But I very clearly have a `catch(const std::exception& ex)` higher up in the call frame in C++/CLI and it *does* get invoked. Here it is (Note that `catch`)

```
bool ScanContext::TryLoad(GsScan^ scan, String^ path, [SRI::Out]ScanContext^% ctx)
{
    try
    {
        ctx = nullptr;
        auto sPath= ToSdk(name);
        ctx =  gcnew ScanContext(scan, gs::LoadScanContext(scan->sdkScan(), sPath));
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;     // This DOES execute
    }

    return ctx != nullptr; // If we did not throw, this is non-null and we succeeded.
}
```

So the `catch` clause above *does* get invoked,  the error output message gets dumped, and control returns normally back to my managed C# code that called into the C++/CLI.

So where did the `SEHException` go?

To double-check, I set the Exceptions dialog to actually break on `SEHException`.  And it sure did.
This is the call stack at the point it breaks.   My C++ code is in the process of throwing `std::runtime_error`

```
    ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()   Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatch() Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!RaiseException() Unknown
>   vcruntime140d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 75 C++
    gscored_v143.dll!gs::detail::YAML::ParseTopLevelMap(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & in) Line 298  C++
    gscored_v143.dll!gs::ScanContext::loadContent(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & is, const std::string & loadFolder) Line 172    C++
    gscored_v143.dll!gs::ScanContext::loadContent(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & is) Line 63 C++
    gscored_v143.dll!gs::ScanContext::Load(const std::shared_ptr<gs::Scan> & scan, const std::string & name) Line 884   C++
    gscored_v143.dll!gs::LoadScanContext(const std::shared_ptr<gs::Scan> & scan, const std::string & name) Line 310 C++
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    MyCompany.Sdk_v143.dll!MyCompany::Sdk::ScanContext::TryLoad(MyCompany::Sdk::Scan^ scan, System::String^ name, MyCompany::Sdk::ScanContext^% ctx) Line 660   C++
    MyCompany.Services.dll!MyCompany.Services.ScanService.GetScanContext(MyCompany.Sdk.Scan scan, string name) Line 1725    C#
```

Is this all just a false warning?

Comment: The debugger displays "first-chance exceptions" to notify you that an exception occurred.  Very helpful to debug an unwise catch-em-all clause, or mysterious code slowdown, or an unexpected exception raised in native code that is handled in managed code.  You'd use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings to make the debugger break on such a first-chance exception.  If it annoys you then right-click the Output window and untick "Exception Messages".

Comment: Hi Hans,  Thanks. I knew that I get first-chance exceptions. I just didn't realize that an SEHException was somehow being inserted between the thrrowing of my unmanaged one and the place I caught it.  If I'm understanding Paul's answer, that's what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

It's not at all obvious from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception?view=net-6.0) exactly what's going on here, but there's an interesting article over at [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175482/Compiler-Internals-How-Try-Catch-Throw-are-Interpr) which explains how (unmanaged) C++ exceptions are handled by the Microsoft compiler.  Basically, when you call `throw` an SEH exception is generated (via [`RaiseException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-raiseexception)) which is then caught and mapped to a C++ exception by the runtime library.

The question now is how that is mapped to a managed C++ exception so that you can catch it in managed code, and the mechanics behind that is not at all clear, but `SEHException` obviously fits into it somehow.

Perhaps the .NET framework catches your unmanaged `throw` via its own `try` ... `catch` block and calls `RaiseException` again with a different exception code (one that corresponds to / results in an `SEHException`), and that's what you're trapping in the debugger.  It then catches that (via [`__try` ... `__except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=msvc-170)) and uses some sort of magic to generate a managed code exception.  Something like that, anyway.

As for whether you need to be concerned about this, the documentation goes on to say:

> Note that the SEHException class does not cause unmanaged C++ exception destructors to be called. To ensure that unmanaged C++ exception destructors are called, use the following syntax in the catch block.

```
C#
catch  
{  
     // Handle catch here.  
}
```

Now I'm really not sure what they mean by 'C++ exception destructors' (I didn't know there was such a thing) but it may be that `yamlmap` doesn't get properly destroyed.  I'd be surprised if that were true, but it might be worth checking.  It also doesn't make sense to me to handle the exception in *managed* code.  Maybe that's just a typo.

Returning to that Code Project article, it cites the fact that the exception code for the SEH exception raised by an unmanaged C++ `throw` is `0xE06D7363`.  If you break on that, you might learn a bit more about all this.  And then again, maybe not.

Comment: Ah.  All this time I thought that when you saw `SEHException`, it meant only that you *had allowed an unmanaged exception to escape your C++/CLI code*.  The runtime does catch such exceptions and translate them into `SEHException` for you.  That part I was familiar with.   I didn't realize that `SEHException' is what allows your C++/CLI to catch the unmanaged exception in the first place.

Comment: Well that's what I'm assuming, reading between the lines.  Like I say, given the state of the documentation it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I think that last bit (about the empty catch clause) is either wrong or out of date.  Because  anything derived from `std::exception` gets caught just fine by my `catch(const std::exception&)` clause.  I've never needed an empty one in C#

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me at all, actually.  I think you're supposed to do some kind of (unmanaged) cleanup in there, but then you wouldn't do that from C#.  Best just to check if `yamlmap ` is destroyed when you throw.

Comment: Well it's a stack-based object so it's guaranteed to be destroyed

Comment: Not necessarily.  The compiler generates code to call the destructor (if there is one) when the function exits, and if `throw` bypasses that for any reason then it wont get called.  Normally, that would never happen of course, but I'm still wondering what that paragraph really means.