# C++ std::filesystem::copy throws weird exception : CommonUtil::CHResultExceptionImpl

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++17

**This is a Windows specific problem.**

I am trying to use `std::filesystem::copy()` to copy a directory's contents to another directory.

When debugging into my C++ program , I notice that a weird exception occurs after executing `std::filesystem::copy()`. This exception can only be seen when debugging and can't be caught.

I tested it with other directories and the exception didn't occur for them.

**Here is how The exception occurs :**

---

I copy the contents from a  directory called `test_fail` structured like so :

```
                                 test_fail
                                     |
               ----------------------------------------------
               |                                            |
          Subdirectory                                 Subdirectory
               |                                            |
         --------------                          -------------------------
               |                                 |                       |
            1 file                            7 files               Subdirectory
                                                                    -------------
                                                                         |
                                                                      3 files
```

The copied contents will go into an empty directory called `test`.

Every file has is 1 KB of size **(Every file only has the string "hello" in it )**

---

**Here is my code :**

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;


int main() {

    // The path of the Directory that produces the exception :  CommonUtil::CHResultExceptionImpl

    std::string failing_Directory = "C:\\Users\\Ibrahim\\test_fail"; 


    // Copying the failing Directory to specifed directory in a try block ,
    // instead of catching the exception it just copies the contents and the function returns.

    // I'm using options "fs::copy_options::recursive | fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing"
    // to copy all files as well as subdirectories to the specified location as well as overwrite 
    // any overwrite the existing directories and files that are duplicates

    try {
        fs::copy(failing_Directory, "C:\\Users\\Ibrahim\\test", fs::copy_options::recursive | fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {

    // The Program doesnt enter this catch

        printf(e.what());
        return -1;
    }

    // The Program Exits Normally
}
```

**Screenshot of where the exception occurs :**

[image]

You can see the exception occur only while debugging , for some reason .

Although my code works fine with the exception , why is this happening ?

Is this a bug in Visual Studio ?

**Thank you**

Comment: Interesting, no hits for that exception on Google, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19501218/5743288) should give you an idea of what's going on.  It looks like some internal implementation detail that happens to get caught by the debugger, I doubt it's anything to worry about if the copy is completing successfully.  And if it keeps popping up in the debugger (does it?) then I believe you can tell MSVC to ignore it, although it will still get logged in the output window.

Comment: just ignore it, somewhere in the standard library its throwing but then catching an exception. The exception is happening whether you are debugging or not but you just don't see it if there's no debugger to notice the internal exception

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, like in [this somewhat related example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069539/how-can-this-warning-of-interopservices-sehexception-be-real).

Comment: Hi , isn't this a bug that needs to be fixed ?

Comment: @iber999 Why is it a bug?  It's just something going on in Microsoft's implementation of the standard library that we don't understand and has this slightly weird side-effect.  You could 'report a problem' (via Visual Studio), but I think they'd just think it was noise.

Comment: Alright , I've opened a bug report on Azure DevOps :https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-17-std::filesystem::copy-throws-weir/10024176?space=62&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=C%2B%2B+std%3A%3Afilesystem&entry=myfeedback

Comment: very much not a bug, the standard library is free to internally throw as many exceptions as it likes as long as they are caught somewhere, it might be detrimental to performance but its not going to break anything